# How do you read in a .txt file with vertical bar separators (while ignoring other possible separators) in R?

Tags: r, txt, read.table

My text data is consistently separated by vertical lines ("|"), but the text between the vertical lines is rarely consistent and often includes characters that could be used as separators ("-", ",", and carriage returns). I would like there to only be 2 columns (report number and comment).

Goal:

| ReportNumber | Report |
| --- | --- |
| 4312822 | Comment: This person did a great job working with other -Class standing was 15/265 -Final academic average/standing was 83.51% /209 out of 265 |
| 3059758 | Comment, Part I: This is a dummy report. |

What the data looks like:

4312822|Comment: This person did a great job working with others.
-Class standing was 1/10
-Final academic average/standing was 83.51% /209 out of 265|

3059758|Comment, Part I: This is a dummy report.|

I've tried both read.delim and read.table:

```
Reports = read.delim('reports.txt', sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skipNul = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

The result, however, is jumbled and not split neatly by the "|"

Comment: try `data.table::fread(myfile, sep = "|")`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `readr` package's function, `read_delim`.
`readr` is available on CRAN, so you can install it from within an R session:

```
install.packages("readr")
readr::read_delim("a;a|b,b|c.c|d:d
", delim = "|", col_names = FALSE)
```

To ensure that the above example works, be sure that you split the first character vector over two lines, ie, you need to include a carriage return.

Then, to actually use it with your file, you'd type, within an R session,

```
readr::read_delim("reports.txt", delim = "|")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that (and fread method that Wimpel suggested) didn't work with carriage returns, I will try to strip out to returns and try again with readr.

Comment: How do you distinguish between a carriage return that denotes a new record and one that doesn't denote a new record?

Comment: I would like to ignore carriage returns completely when it comes to records and only separate by "|" (due to how different all of the records are with some having multiple lines, some with bullet points, and some a single sentences). When I read the data in, however, it looks like the carriage returns are interpreted as new/different records.

Comment: How are carriage returns encoded in your file? \n? "\n"? "\\n"?

Comment: Also, which character is at the end of your lines? How do you know where the end of a line is?